# Angular 2 CLI - php for index file instead of html file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a way to change an Angular 2 application that is created and served via Angular 2 CLI from the default html file to a php file?  Is there a setting someplace that determines with the ng serve command serves up as the default index file?

MBU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that angular cli does not allow you to set default file name to something different than index.html.

Even if the change to index.php would be possible, you will not accomplish what you want. To run php files, you need PHP interpreter. There is no such thing in ng serve, as it's main purpose is to serve static HTML files.