# How can I properly replace/rename Angular index.html file to index.php?

Tags: php, angular

In my Angular project, I need to use PHP in index.html file. I already renamed it to index.php and updated angular.json to use index.php in index property.

My problem is, after running `ng build` command, the PHP codes in the generated index.php file in dist directory are commented.

```
<!--?php
$websiteCode = getenv('SITE_CODE');
?--><!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ClientPortal</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c.css"></head>
<body>
  <!--?=$websiteCode?-->
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.f3b55109ab97bda870bd.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.a58f45ef9ccddb12523d.js" defer></script><script src="main.6629fcd1d3960ef0deb9.js" defer></script>

</body></html>
```

Is there a configuration I need to update or specify so that PHP codes will not be commented? I am using Angular 12.
This is working fine in my existing Angular projects using Angular 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 CLI - php for index file instead of html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665982/angular-2-cli-php-for-index-file-instead-of-html-file)

Comment: @Grzegorz, unfortunately no. it works by renaming the file, but the PHP codes in the output index.php file are commented

Comment: Please read the linked thread carefully @PrinceG, it says there's no way `ng serve` (and I think `ng build` would have the same limitations for the same reasons) to work with PHP. You need to pass those server side data to your angular app in a different way.

Comment: i solved it by setting `"optimization": {"styles": {"inlineCritical": false}}`.

Comment: @PrinceG can you share what configuration you made to angular.json file to run php code in angular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour seems to be a bug. It's caused by a CSS optimizer. Disabling the `inlineCritical` fixes the issue (see https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-optimization-options).

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "fubar": {
      "projectType": "library",
      ...
    },
    "acme": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": { ... },
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              ...
              "optimization": {  <-- ADDING THIS HAS SOLVED THE ISSUE FOR ME.
                "styles": {
                  "inlineCritical": false
                }
              }
            },
            "development": {
              ...
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "..."
        },
        "serve": {
          ...
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          ...
        },
        "test": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "acme"
}
```

It's important to note the difference in build time which indicate that the optimization that got disabled was not a trivial task.

[image]