# Angular build process is commenting out PHP tags

Tags: php, angular, angular-cli, ng-build

I asking my first Angular-related question. Please bear with me if it has already been answered. Hopefully, you know the answer and have time to share it.

**My current use case is the following:**

1. After building the Angular app, the default page must be `index.php`  (I have that currently working)
2. The index.php file contains a PHP logic which is required for various things. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the PHP logic needs to inject a special dynamic metatag in the HTML . Values for that metatag are inherited from a parent non-Angular app (a plain old-fashioned CMS).
3. I am using the latest Angular version.

**My current issue:**

Whenever I run `ng build`, PHP tags in my `index.php` file get converted from `<?php ... ?>` to `<--?php ... ?-->`.

**Questions**

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there any way to configure this behaviour?

Many thanks in advance. I appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68016179/), a CSS optimizer causes that potential bug. The solution is to disable [inlineCritical](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-optimization-options) like this:

> Add this option in angular.json, in each build/configuration :
>
> ```
> "optimization": {
>             "styles": {
>               "inlineCritical": false
>             }
>           }
> ```